# Locking the select box after picking a choice?

Tags: javascript, html

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/favakevuhu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

In the bin above, how would I lock the select box after making a choice, so that you can't select another choice?

Like if I select 'yes', I'd want it to lock so you can't change the choice to 'no'.

I've done something like this with `input`, and using `onblur` and `contenteditable = false` to lock the `input` box. But I'm not sure if you can do `contenteditable` with `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `el.disabled = true` inside the onchange to make the input uneditable